# Unable to connect to SFTP server Apache common

Tags: java, apache, file-upload, sftp, pgp

I have wrote a java code (using apache common vfs2) to upload files to SFTP server. Recently, I have introduced PGP Security on my server. Now, the java code is not able to connect to this server. Connection with FileZilla is successful. We are using CrushFTP on server and apache-common-vfs2 in java application. Here is the code snippet

```
String originalFileName = localFile.getName();
manager.init();
FileObject fileToUpload = manager.resolveFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());

// Create remote file object
FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(
              createConnectionString(originalFileName),
               createDefaultFileSystemOptions());

remoteFile.copyFrom(fileToUpload, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
```

Methods

```
public String createConnectionString(String fileName) {
    String path = "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server +workingDir+"/"+fileName;
    logger.info("uploading file at "+path);
    return path;
}

public static FileSystemOptions createDefaultFileSystemOptions()
                            throws FileSystemException {
    // Create SFTP options
    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

    // SSH Key checking
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");

   // Root directory set to user home
   SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);

   // Timeout is count by Milliseconds
   SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);
   return opts;
}
```

The exception is as follow

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "192.168.13.102".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
```

Anoney please suggest solution?

Comment: SFTP does not support the OpenPGP protocol at all, it relies on the TLS standard instead. You might be transmitting OpenPGP encrypted files as payload through an SFTP channel encrypted with TLS (which means you'd be encrypting twize), but the SFTP transfer does not have anything to do with OpenPGP at all.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates you're using a [Java release older than 1.8](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044060) and [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) parameters larger than 1024 bits. Either update the JDK release to 1.8 or newer, or limit to 1024 bit Diffie-Hellman parameters on the server side (how to do depends on the server software in use, and is server configuration work better asked at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)).